# Only some UIButtons work with customisation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm currently developing an iPad application and want to apply a custom font to the UIButtons on a certain screen.  I have noticed similar problems with other screens, namely that the text on some (seemingly random) UIButtons disappears.  In this case, the custom font is being applied to some buttons but not others, again there doesn't seem to be any pattern as to which buttons work and which don't.  I've attached a screenshot below to try to give you an idea of what exactly I mean.

As I've mentioned, on some other screens I have noticed text completely disappearing from some buttons and have had to replace these with images featuring the text instead.

[image]

All buttons are created in Interface Builder. They use attributed text to allow multiple lines and centred alignment. Any help would be much appreciated.

**edit - my code is like the following:**

```
for (UIView *sub in view.subviews) {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sub;
    UILabel *lbl = [btn titleLabel];
    [lbl setFont: myFont size: mySize];
}
```

Comment: Attributed or plane text? What `UIControlState` state? Posting some code will probably be required.

Comment: @Zaph - updated question with my code.  Using attributed text.

Comment: Have you checked that all of your buttons are in the array of views that you're iterating through, by logging their content in the loop for example? Also, where is that loop performed in your view controller?

Comment: Yes, all buttons are being "hit", so to speak. The loop is performed in the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Also, is the State Config property in Interface Builder set to default for all of the buttons?

Comment: Upon further investigation (I apologise) - it appears that some buttons I have kept as "Plain" text - these are the ones acting as expected.  It is the buttons using "Attributed" text that are not working - is there a different property I should be setting for the Attributed text button labels?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but I was going to comment that you don't need attributed strings to achieve centered and multiple line labels.

Comment: I was wondering about that myself, however when I click the centre align button under "Plain" text, it simply shifts both lines to the centre of the button, whilst remaining left aligned, rather than centre aligning them.

Comment: Try adding this to your for loop: lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; lbl.numberOfLines = 0;

Comment: Darren, that worked perfectly.  Add as an answer, mentioning the other answers/comments, and I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments:

You can achieve centered and multiline title labels in UIButtons without using NSAttributedStrings by adding the following lines to your for loop:

```
lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; 
lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

To use attributed insure the IB items are set to use attributed text, not plain text.

To set the attributed title for a `NSButton` use:

```
- (NSAttributedString *)attributedTitleForState:(UIControlState)state
```

for a `NSLabel` use:

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSAttributedString *attributedText
```

Of course you may not need attributed text is all you are doing is just setting a font and alignment.

For multiple lines of text set:

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger numberOfLines
```

as appropriate.

Comment: couldn't get Attributed Text working at all, so have gone with Darren's answer.  Thank you for your help, upvoted.